# jQuery validationEngine => onSuccess don't seems to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

First try here, I tried for last 3 nights everything possible with the jQuery plugin, to get a very simple thing :

> When I submit a form (target = iframe), works fine, and I just need when it's validated to "unhide" a div... I tried every single fichtion without success.

Unfortunately nothing I tried works.

I searched on official site, but no documentation for "onSuccess"... just :

onSuccess
If set, this callback function will be called when all validations passed.

So maybe someone may help me :

```
$('#MYFORM').validationEngine('attach', {
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if (status == true) {                   
            alert('success'); << EVEN THIS DOESNT WORKS, FORM SUBMITS OR DISPLAY MISSING FIELDS
        }
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and thanks for help.

In fact I just have 2 fields (I used so many times this plugin so know how it works, and it works perfect for validation).

I added : `class="validate[required,length[5,100]]"` to each of both fields

the form is so classic...

```
<form name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM" action="target.cgi">
```

So I tried to add the code above to "validate", and if validated show a div "WORK IN PROGRESS"...

```
$('#MYFORM').validationEngine('attach', {
onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
    if (status == true) {                   
        alert('success'); << EVEN THIS DOESNT WORKS, FORM SUBMITS OR DISPLAY MISSING FIELDS
    }
}
```

For test, I triet everythnig and had idea to display a very small "alert", but nothing happens.

In fact onsubmitr "and if the validation is OK" I need to show the DIV before "submit"... but never worked, tried every thing I read... so I'll write my own routine :P without use validation plugin.

Any idea ?